# Need to check condition and print -python

Tags: python

I have a variable with dynamic values(not same always)

Ex:

```
s = '''
:20:name
:21A:Address
:22B:phone
:57A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:59B:/REST_MA
LINE1
:59C:TEST
'''
```

each and every time values may differ but constantly I want to check for three values
 :57A:, :58A: and :59A:

I have written code like

```
a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
a = a.split(':')[2]
print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
print("value of B:" + b)
c, d = s[s.index(':58A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
c = c.split(':')[2]
print("value of C:" +c[1:7])
print("value of D:" +d)

e, f = s[s.index(':59A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
e = e.split(':')[2]
print("value of E:"+ e[1:7])
print("value of F:" +f)
```

but not necessary to have all three values(:57A:, :58A: and :59A:) at a time 
if I have all three values then my code is working
if not its throwing below error:

256789
TEST VALUE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 16, in 
ValueError: substring not found

Note: I'm constantly checking for 256789422254 and TEST VALUE in three fields (:57A:, :58A: and :59A:) but not necessary to have all three fields at a time. If value is there in these three fields then I want to print else not needed

Expected o/p
value of A:256789
value of B:TEST VALUE

here there is no :58A: value so its throwing error, so need to check whether value is there or not before printing.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: In which line of your code this error occur, to which part of code line 16 correspond ? It seems to me that when you want to extract [:2] you have less than 2 characters in the string.

Comment: You could test `if ':57A:' in s` before trying to find its `index`. But if you tell us exactly what  output you want, we could help you achieve it in a much nicer and cleaner way.

Comment: @PySaad  if variable 'S' have that value then I need to print otherwise just need to  ignore.Here in my condition the value which I want to print is not available in 'S' thats why throwing error.

Comment: Please edit your question and be accurate. Provide the exact output you would like for your sample input.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm constantly checking for 256789422254 and TEST VALUE in three fields (:57A:, :58A: and :59A:) but not necessary  to have all three fields at a time. If value is there in these three fields then I want to print else not needed.

Comment: Please include in your question **the exact output you expect**, not some vague description of it. Looking at your current code, there are 6 `print` instructions, and you say that you want to print 3 things. So, please, exact expected output for the sample input at the start of your question.

Comment: a, b = s[s.index(':57A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
a = a.split(':')[2]
print("value of A:" + a[1:7])
print("value of B:" + b)  This condition itself working but only thing I want to validate before print is whether :57A: is available or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
l = s.split('\n')
a = [i for i in l if i.startswith(':57A:')]
a = a[0].split(':')[2] if a else ''
print(a)


b = [i for i in l if i.startswith(':58A:')]
b = b[0].split(':')[2] if b else ''
print(b)

c = [i for i in l if i.startswith(':59A:')]
c = c[0].split(':')[2] if c else ''
print(c)
```

However this approach will work if the split lines only start with `:57A:` or `:58A:` or `:59A:` whenever they are present. If for a case the split line is like `'.....:59A:123abc', you need to check with`in` operator like :

```
l = s.split('\n')
a = [i for i in l if ':57A:' in i]
a = a[0].split(':')[2] if a else ''
print(a)


b = [i for i in l if ':58A:' in i]
b = b[0].split(':')[2] if b else ''
print(b)

c = [i for i in l if ':59A:' in i]
c = c[0].split(':')[2] if c else ''
print(c)
```

Output in both the cases :

```
'/256789422254'
''
''
```

Comment: This will fail if ':57A:' isn't present in the string, so this is not a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille This shouldn't fail if `':57A:` is not in the string. Check for `b` and `c`.

Comment: It does. `a[0].split(':')[1]` gives `IndexError: list index out of range` in this case. As a side note, please avoid pasting parts of REPL sessions with the >>>, it make copy-pasting really inconvenient.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Agreed that copy pasting code is inconvenient in case of REPL sessions. Edited for convenience.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev thank you I always want next line too.. A:256789 B:TEST VALUE

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev  you clearly got my point if I have :57A: then I need to print o/p like below:value of A is 256789422254
value of B is: TEST VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Consider your index() function.

If substring doesn't exist in the string, you get a ValueError exception. 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index

Perhaps check if the text `:58A` (or variants) are in the string before getting the index and splitting it.